# Use Map on a Function with two variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I am new to *Mathematica* and I would like to find out how to use `Map` on a function with two parameters such as:

```
function[a_, b_] := (Return[a+b])
```

Something like this is what I need:

```
Map[function,{{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}]
```

I want *Mathematica* to compute 1+1, then 2+2 and so on.

Sorry for the noob question, but I found nothing in the reference

Comment: Try `MapThread` instead of `Map`

Comment: aside, just do `function[a_, b_] := a+b`.  `Return` is needed in mathematica very rarely and often does not behave as you might expect.

Comment: Indeed, in *Mathematica* you should almost never use `Return` in the way it is used in other languages.  For your specific example, just run `a+b` when the lists `a` and `b` are separate (not grouped into another list).

Comment: Thanks to all of you...i do my best not to annoy you With noob questions..thanks again

Comment: Use `Apply` instead of `Map`, try `function @@@ Transpose[{{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}]`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b
Thread[f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]]
```

> `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`

And just to show you a little more *Mathematica* kung-foo, consider:

```
g[a_, b_] /; a < b := Row[{a, " is less than ", b}]
g[a_, b_] /; a > b := Row[{a, " is greater than ", b}]
g[a_, b_] /; a == b := Row[{a, " is equal to ", b}]

With[{nums = Range[5]}, Column @ Thread[g[nums, Reverse[nums]]]]
```

[image: result]

Not at all like java or c++, but once you get into it, actually a lot nicer.

Comment: Why is the `Thread` needed? Just using `f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]` also gives `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}`.

Comment: 'Plus' is Listable so Thread is not required for the specific case but woukd be for the more general case  @Bills